# std::function and std::packaged_task conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I am trying to move a `std::packaged_task` into a `std::vector` of `std::function<void()>`, because `std::packaged_task` has `void operator()( ArgTypes... args )` overloaded, it should be convertable to `std::function<void()>`, yes?

This doesnt compile both on MSVC and Clang, MSVC complains about cannot convert void to int, clang complains deleted copy constructor for `std::packaged_task`, shouldn't move version of `std::vector::push_back` be called here? what is going on, is this a bug?

```
int main () 
{
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec;
    std::packaged_task<int()> task( [] { return 100; } );
    vec.push_back( std::move(task) );
}
```

Here is the cryptic template error messages for clang

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/string:434:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:594:
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2236:15: error: call to deleted constructor of
      'std::__1::packaged_task<int ()>'
              __first_(_VSTD::forward<_Args1>(get<_I1>(__first_args))...)
              ^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2414:15: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization
      'std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >,
      2>::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<const std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> &,
      const std::__1::allocator<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> > &, 0, 0>'
      requested here
            : base(__pc, _VSTD::move(__first_args), _VSTD::move(__second_args),
              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:996:11: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization
      'std::__1::__compressed_pair<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >
      >::__compressed_pair<const std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> &, const
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> > &>' requested here
        : __f_(piecewise_construct, _VSTD::forward_as_tuple(__f),
          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:1035:17: note: in instantiation of member
      function 'std::__1::__function::__func<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >, void ()>::__func'
      requested here
    ::new (__p) __func(__f_.first(), __f_.second());
                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:1277:26: note: in instantiation of member
      function 'std::__1::__function::__func<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >, void ()>::__clone'
      requested here
            ::new (__f_) _FF(_VSTD::move(__f));
                         ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1681:31: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'std::__1::function<void
      ()>::function<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >' requested here
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1608:18: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization 'std::__1::allocator<std::__1::function<void ()>
      >::construct<std::__1::function<void ()>, std::__1::packaged_task<int ()>
      >' requested here
            {__a.construct(__p, _VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);}
                 ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:1492:14: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::function<void
      ()> > >::__construct<std::__1::function<void ()>,
      std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >' requested here
            {__construct(__has_construct<allocator_type, pointer, _Args...>(),
             ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/vector:1519:25: note: in instantiation of function
      template specialization
      'std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::function<void
      ()> > >::construct<std::__1::function<void ()>,
      std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >' requested here
        __alloc_traits::construct(this->__alloc(),
                        ^
main.cpp:19:6: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::vector<std::__1::function<void ()>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::function<void ()> >
      >::emplace_back<std::__1::packaged_task<int ()> >' requested here
        vec.emplace_back( std::move(task) );
            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/future:1956:5: note: function has been explicitly marked
      deleted here
    packaged_task(const packaged_task&) = delete;
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: Could you please include the exact error messages?

Comment: And that was just for two errors.

Comment: `std::packaged_task<Sig>` is move-only. `std::function<Sig>` only works with copyable functors (and that are compatible with `Sig`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> it should be convertable to `std::function<void()>`, yes?

No. The relevant constructor of `function` requires its argument to be CopyConstructible and `packaged_task` is not CopyConstructible, it is only MoveConstructible, because its copy constructor and copy assignment operator are deleted.  This is an unfortunate requirement of `function` but necessary for `function` to be copyable, due to using type erasure to abstract away the details of the wrapped callable object.

Until quite late in the process the C++0x draft didn't require CopyConstructible but it was added to the final C++11 standard by [DR 1287](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1287) so it's my fault, sorry ;-)  An earlier concept-enabled draft *had* required the `CopyConstructible` concept, but that got lost when concepts were removed from the draft.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact problem today. When implementing a synchronous call in terms of an asynchronous service, the obvious thing to do is to try to store a packaged_task in a handler function so that the caller's future can be made ready when the asynchronous handler completes.

Unfortunately c++11 (and 14) don't allow this. Tracking it down cost me nearly a day of development time, and the process led me to this answer.

I knocked up a solution - a replacement for std::function with a specialisation for std::packaged_task.

Thanks both yngum and Jonathan for posting the question and the answer.

code:

```
// general template form
template<class Callable>
struct universal_call;

// partial specialisation to cover most cases
template<class R, class...Args>
struct universal_call<R(Args...)> {
    template<class Callable>
    universal_call(Callable&& callable)
    : _impl { std::make_shared<model<Callable>>(std::forward<Callable>(callable)) }
    {}

    R operator()(Args&&...args) const {
        return _impl->call(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
private:
    struct concept {
        virtual R call(Args&&...args) = 0;
        virtual ~concept() = default;
    };

    template<class Callable>
    struct model : concept {
        model(Callable&& callable)
        : _callable(std::move(callable))
        {}
        R call(Args&&...args) override {
            return _callable(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        Callable _callable;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<concept> _impl;
};

// pathalogical specialisation for std::packaged_task - 
// erases the return type from the signature
template<class R, class...Args>
struct universal_call<std::packaged_task<R(Args...)>>
: universal_call<void(Args...)>
{
    using universal_call<void(Args...)>::universal_call;
};

// (possibly) helpful function
template<class F>
universal_call<F> make_universal_call(F&& f)
{
    return universal_call<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<concept> _impl;` seems better than `std::shared_ptr<concept> _impl; ` here, since unique_ptr is lighter.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin today, yes. I think back then asio's handlers weren't move-aware (or I wasn't aware that they were) so I went for a shared-copy solution. Today I would use a unique_ptr without doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had similar issue.
With c++14 and lambda capture initialization we can write:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec;
using task_t = std::packaged_task<int()>;
task_t task([] { return 100; });
vec.emplace_back( [t = std::make_shared<task_t>(std::move(task))]() {
    (*t)();
});
```