# Pretending packaged_task is copy constructable

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

I've been looking for a workaround to the [problem of type-erasing a `std::packaged_task` using `std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16889885/168175).

What I wanted to do was something like this:

```
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  std::function<void()> task;
  std::future<int> make(int val) {
    auto test = std::packaged_task<int()>([val](){
      return val;
    });

    auto fut = test.get_future();
    task = std::move(test);
    return fut;
  }
}

int main() {
   auto fut = make(100);
   task();
   std::cout << fut.get() << "\n";
}
```

it's succinct and avoids re-implementing a lot of mechanics myself. Unfortunately that isn't actually legal because `std::packaged_task` is move-only not copy constructable.

As a workaround I came up with the following, which implements things in terms of `std::promise` and a `std::shared_ptr` instead:

```
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  std::function<void()> task;

  std::future<int> make(int val) {
    auto test = std::make_shared<std::promise<int>>();

    task = [test,val]() {
      test->set_value(val);
      test.reset(); // This is important
    };

    return test->get_future();
  }
}

int main() {
   auto fut = make(100);
   task();
   std::cout << fut.get() << "\n";
}
```

This "works for me", but is this actually correct code? Is there a nicer way to achieve the same net result?

(Note that the lifespan of the `std::shared_ptr` in the second example is important for my real code. Clearly as-is I will be taking steps to prevent calling the same `std::function` twice).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to stem from type incompatabilities:

```
std::function<void()> task;  // Notice this is not a package_task
```

So why would you expect this to work?

```
task = std::move(test);  // when test is `std::packaged_task<int()>`
```

When I change task to the correct type it compiles as expected:

```
namespace {

  std::packaged_task<int()> task;          // Change this.

  std::future<int> make(int val) {
    auto test = std::packaged_task<int()>([val](){
      return val;
    });

    auto fut = test.get_future();
    task = std::move(test);              // This now compiles.
    return fut;
  }
}
```

Personally since type is important I would remove the `auto` from `test`.

```
namespace {

    std::packaged_task<int()> task;

    std::future<int> make(int val) {
        std::packaged_task<int()> test([val](){return val;});

        auto fut = test.get_future();
        task     = std::move(test);
        return fut;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `std::function<void()> task` was deliberate, not a bug - it's meant to type-erase the `operator()` of `std::packaged_task`. I expected it to work because of implicit conversions, http://ideone.com/SizOtq works and the only reason it didn't work in the original is because the copy constructor of `std::packaged_task` is deleted.